# Using lwuit in netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: netbeans-6.9, lwuit

Please i need help on what to do to use lwuit in netbeans6.9.1. i have the lWUIT.jar file and i have added it to my project; an helloworld application but when i run the application, the emulator opens up and doesnt display anything. i have tried all emulators but it is to no avail. other applications not using lwuit are working fine.
please help, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The Hello tutorial is even a bit brief. Why not try the Recipe Book Hands-on-Lab from the LWUIT blog [here](http://www.lwuit.com/2011/09/recipe-book-hol-draft.html).
I hope you are also using LWUIT 1.5? If not, download it and use that one, and its Resource Editor. It even has the option to help you configure/link to your netbeans installation on your system.
I use netbeans 6.9.1 myself and the integration is seamless